# how do I capture polling data from an Arduino into python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, console, buffer, sensors

I have serial data being output from an arduino nano console via /dev/ttyUSB0 to a Pi3 cli.

data sample from buffer:

```
Soil Moisture = 697
Soil Moisture = 699
Soil Moisture = 698
Soil Moisture = 697
Soil Moisture = 699
```

How do I capture this polling data for using in Python 3.x?

i.e.

```
import some_magic_library_to_make_my_life_easy
???
print(my_polling_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [PySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) package. It does exactly what you want!

Simple example:

```
import serial

baudrate = 9600
port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'

ard = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=5)

while True:
    data = ard.readline()
    print(data)
```